# As3 hit test with programmatically added movieclips (without instance names)

Tags: actionscript-3, dynamic, multiple-instances, hittest, addchild

I have a main class where I have the functionality to add a wall to the stage.

Previously, I declared this as

```
public var wall_cubular_1:Wall_cubular_1 = new Wall_cubular_1();
```

and then added it like this

```
addChild(wall_cubular_1);
```

And then in the character class (which are supposed to hittest the walls) I had the following

```
wallHit = this.hitTestObject(_root.wall_cubular_1)
```

However, this meant I could only place one wall at a time from the main class, since every time I added a new one, the old one just vanished and the new one was placed. As if I replaced it.

So I changed the main class, removing the public var of the wall, and instead had it setup like this

```
var wall_cubular_1:Wall_cubular_1 = new Wall_cubular_1();
addChild(wall_cubular_1);
```

in the function which adds the walls.

Now the characters can't hit test the walls as it isn't public. So I tried changing the hittest to this

```
wallHit = this.hitTestObject(stage.wall_cubular_1)
```

But it doesn't work!

I'm totally lost. How do I fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In your, `character` class you can `Dispatch Event` say `wallHit` like so,

`dispatchEvent(new Event("wallHit"));`

In your main class,

(I am assuming you are creating instance `character` class in `Main` class).
(Also, you will need to create instance of `wallHit` in `Main` class).

```
characterClassInstance.addEventListener("wallHit", onWallHit);

private function onWallHit(e:Event):void
{
     //Here you can add your collision detection logic
     wallHit = this.hitTestObject(_root.wall_cubular_1);
}
```